# Azure Database connect through OpenTextSocket proxy client in heidisql DB connector tool is works, but from java code its not works

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure-sql-database, database-connection, heidisql

Azure Database connect through OpenTextSocket proxy client in heidisql DB connector tool is works, but from java code its not works,
Spring boot application connection with database

Screenshot :
[image]
address : hostXXXX/1.0.0.1

And HeidiSQl tool is using libpq-12.dll to connect postgres Database,
but Java code is using Driver Class, so may be is have some issue ?

Connection URL : jdbc:postgresql://XXX.postgres.database.azure.com:5432/dev

Error :

```
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:158)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:116)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79)
        
    
    ... 24 common frames omitted
        Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Bad address: connect
            at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
            at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:105)
            at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
            at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
            at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
            at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
            at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
            at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:231)
            at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:95)
            at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:98)
            at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:213)
            ... 38 common f
```

Comment: Azure SQL database doesn't support the IP address, please use the whole Azure SQL database name like: `servername.database.windows.net`.

Comment: Yes, I am using to connect with host by using opentextsocket proxy, jdbc:postgresql://XXXX.database.azure.com:5432/dev

Comment: If you are use postgresql database, it should be `jdbc:postgresql://XXX.postgres.database.azure.com:5432/dev`

Comment: yes, using this one jdbc:postgresql://XXX.postgres.database.azure.com:5432/dev